# Can I prevent a nuget package from loading all of its dependencies?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package-restore, nuspec

My C# .Net Framework 4.7.2 project is using a NuGet package, call it package A.  Package A has a package reference to package B.  Package B causes me issues and I don't want it in my project.  Package B is only a dependency due to the default implementation of an interface provided in package A.  I can provide a new implementation of the interface, but how can I prevent a NuGet restore from pulling in the unwanted and now unneeded Package B?

Comment: You can just delete the Package B in `packages.config` file and also delete it in `xxx.csproj` file and then you can avoid using unneeded Package B.

Comment: Hi, please check if my answer helps you handle your original issue and feel free to let us know or if you already have a solution, you can share it with us here. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can provide a new implementation of the interface, but how can I
>   prevent a NuGet restore from pulling in the unwanted and now unneeded
>   Package B?

Since you have installed Package A with its dependency Package B in your project, you could try these:

**First**, try to enter your `packages.config` file and delete Package B like this:

Delete this:

```
<package id="Package B" version="xxx" targetFramework="net472" />
```

**Second**,  delete Package B under `xxx.csproj` file(unload your project-->`Edit xxx.csproj`) and delete this:

```
<Reference Include="Package B, Version=xxx Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\xxx\PackageB.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

**Then** reload your project and it will not load Package B during Restore step or Build time.

**In addition**, if you want to install a nuget package without its dependencies, you can try to run this under `Tools`-->`NuGet Package Manager`-->`Nuget Packager Console`:

```
Install-Package <package name> -IgnoreDependencies
```

It will not install all dependencies of the nuget package.

If there is more than one dependency in your nuget package and you only want to remove one of them, you can only install the nuget package and all the dependencies as usual and then remove the nuget package using my solution.